# Delete file ending with .csv, .html, .doc in java

Tags: java, file

I want to delete a file ending with .csv,.html,.doc.. I have to upload a file to the remote location. After uploading the file, it should be deleted form the localpath.
I have written code which is working perfectly for one function but not for another function. My code snippet:

```
localfilePath="D:/archives/shai/aaabrowser.csv";

if (isFileTransferComplete == false){
                    error ="SFTP failure";
                    if(isFileTobeDeleted){
                          File target = new File(localfilePath);
                          target.delete();      
                        }
             }
```

please help

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? You could also add some logs to see if the flow is executed as expected.

Comment: There is no exception...The flow is executed correctly but file is nt getting deleted from path

Comment: Your logic just seems wrong. I assume `isFileTransferComplete` is used to test when the file has been uploaded; if that's false (the file hasn't been uploaded) why are you trying to delete the local copy?

Comment: isfiletrasferComplete if its false, then the file needs to be deleted from the local path, this is the requirement...if the file is nt uploaded to the remote path the it should be deleted from the local path also....

Comment: @Rachel That's not what you implied in the question; "I have to upload a file to the remote location. After uploading the file, it should be deleted form the localpath." However, if your code is correct for what you actually need to do, just ignore my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

There might still be an open file handle that prevents the file from being deleted. Sometime the JVM holds those handles and the file can be deleted once the JVM is shut down (there is a `deleteOnExit()` method).

The `delete()` method returns a boolean to indicate success or failure, so check that.

Alternatively, try Apache Commons FileIO which has a method [`FileUtils.forceDelete( file )`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete%28java.io.File%29), that throws an exception when it fails.